# Mysql REGEXP find year range

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to separate the contents in the table on my movie site according to year intervals, but no matter how hard I tried, I could not succeed.
Actually, what I want is to list movie files before `1950`.
I have no idea if I'm making a syntax error as I'm a beginner

```
A Movie 1910
B Movie 1920
C Movie 1930
D Movie 1940
E Movie 1950
F Movie 1970
G Movie 1990


SELECT * FROM streams WHERE type='movie' AND filename REGEXP '/^(190[1-9]\d|194\d)$/';
```

Comment: `^` matches the beginning of the string. The year isn't at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

The year is at the end of the filename, not the beginning, so you need to remove the `^` anchor.

You have an extra `0` after `19`, so you're matching 5-digit years that begin with `190`, not 4-digit years that begin with `19`.

You don't put `/` delimiters around the regexp in SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM streams 
WHERE type='movie' 
AND filename REGEXP '19[0-4]\\d$';
```

If you're using MySQL 5.x rather than 8.x, it doesn't support escape sequences like `\d`. Replace that with `[0-9]` to match digits.

Comment: I tested this online and it worked! But I think there is an escape problem caused by mysql version. How can I fix this?

`Server version: 10.8.3-MariaDB-1:10.8.3+maria~focal`

Comment: MariaDB has used PCRE since 10.0.5, so the escape sequence should work. You need to double the backslash in a regexp.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't succeed :( I need to list the contents between 1900 and 1950... I'm working with Navicat

Comment: You don't put `/` delimiters around the regexp in SQL.